# How to show that $\sum_{i\ge i_0} \frac{i^2}{4^i}\to 0$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

How to show that: for all $\varepsilon>0$, take a $i_0=i_0(\varepsilon)$ such that

$$\sum_{i\ge i_0} \frac{i^2}{4^i}\le \varepsilon.$$

I know that is convergence to zero by the ratio test but how to choose $i_0$?

Comment: You don't need to find the $i_0$ explicitly if the question only asks for existence.

Comment: @player3236 But this question asks for the exact $i_0$.

Comment: As currently stated, the question only asks for the existence of an $i_0$ for each $\epsilon > 0$, which is immediate from the definition of a convergent sequence.

Comment: @player3236 Well, I just want to take a proper $i_0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Use induction to prove that $\frac {i^{2}} {4^{i}} \leq \frac  1{(1.5)^{i}}$ for all $i \geq 1$. Since $\sum_{i \geq i_0} \frac  1{(1.5)^{i}}$ is a geometric sum you can compute it explicitly and find $i_0$ such that the sum is less than $\epsilon$.

Comment: Why not just choose $i^2/4^i \le 2^i/4^i=1/2^i$?

Comment: $i^{2} \leq 2^{i}$ is false for $i=3$. @Hermi

Answer (score 1):

$$S_x=\sum_{i=x}^\infty \frac{i^2}{4^i}=\frac{ 4^{1-x}}{27} \left(9 x^2+6 x+5\right)$$ If I properly understook you want to know $x$ such that $S_x \leq \epsilon$ that is to say
$$4^x \geq \frac{4 \left(9 x^2+6 x+5\right)}{27 \epsilon }$$ It is easy to show that, as soon as $x >3$, $9 x^2+6 x+5 < 11x^2$. consider that an upper bound will be given by the solution of
$$4^x=\frac {44}{27} \frac {x^2}{\epsilon }$$

The only analytical solution is given by
$$x=-\frac 1 {\log(2)} W_{-1}\left(-\frac{3}{2} \sqrt{\frac{3}{11}}  \log (2)\,\sqrt{\epsilon }\right)$$ where $W_{-1}(t)$ is the second branch of [Lambert function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function).

Using $\epsilon=10^{-6}$ gives, as real, $x=14.14$, then $\lceil x \rceil=15$ and computing the exact value,

$$S_{15}=\frac{265}{905969664} \sim 2.93 \times 10^{-7} <10^{-6}$$ while
$$S_{14}=\frac{1853}{1811939328} \sim 1.02 \times 10^{-6}>10^{-6}$$

In the linked page, you will find good approximations for the computation of $W_{-1}(t)$ when $t$ is small.